# smart and elegant way to shift data based on the date

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am newsih to Python. I have wrote an script that help me with reading, analysing, manipulating and writing engineering data to a csv file. to have it fully automated, I need to be able to shift the data (Currently doing it in excel), consider the example below for the data set:

- Date_1 Value_A1 Value_B1
- Date_2 Value_A2 Value B2
- Date_3 Value_A3 Value B3
- Date_4 Value_A4 Value B4

I want this to be output as below:

- Date_1 Value_A2 Value_B1
- Date_2 Value_A3 Value B2
- Date_3 Value_A4 Value B3

Notice Value A1 is gone, and the last row of data is removed. but all the data in second column shifted to the previous timestep.

I have tried few different methods, but they consist of positioning different part of the codes before or after other parts to grab data from previous line read before it is getting overwritten by the new line. It proved to be very difficult to follow so if there was error in calculations was difficult to troubleshoot. Just wondering if there is a smart way to achieve this please

Comment: Show us what you tried. This should not be hard; split the columns, print with the second column replaced with the value of the second column from the previous line, remember the second column for the next iteration. The first line is a corner case, there is no previous second column to recall.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with the zip function by combining the list with a copy of itself starting at the second position:

```
data = [ ("Date_1", "Value_A1", "Value_B1"),
         ("Date_2", "Value_A2", "Value B2"),
         ("Date_3", "Value_A3", "Value B3"),
         ("Date_4", "Value_A4", "Value B4")]

shifted = [ (d1[0],d2[1],d1[2]) for d1,d2 in zip(data,data[1:]) ]
for line in shifted: print(line)


# ('Date_1', 'Value_A2', 'Value_B1')
# ('Date_2', 'Value_A3', 'Value B2')
# ('Date_3', 'Value_A4', 'Value B3')
```

Comment: Thanks Alain, This looks very smart and tidy. I will check it out soon, thanks again.